# How to make KDE connect launch at startup?

Tags: kde, startup, connection, file-sharing

I was wondering if there is a way to make KDE connect Launch as soon as the system boots/reboots. I always have to open the KDE connect app to make sure an instance of it is running in the background, is there a way to make sure that it launches as soon as the system is started?

What I have tried: I tried to emulate something I saw for other apps
which is executing these commands in the terminal
sudo kdeconnectd start
sudo kdeconnectd autostart
These haven't helped

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and which flavor are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using Ubuntu with Gnome, you can find an app called "startup Appications" where you can add an entry for kdeconnect

Comment: Thank you! Don't use Ubuntu anymore and in Opensuse it starts with boot.